# html img src not working

Tags: html, notepad

i'm trying to create a simple web page using notepad. 
I want to add a image. but image is not loading.I tried different browsers,but no luck. please help.
image size is 26kb.

here is the code,

```
<html>
<head>
<title>GLOBAL WARMING</title>
</head
<body>
<img src="images.jpg"/img>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: well thats not proper html.

Comment: <img src="images.jpg"</img> you have an error in the code.

Comment: instead of the "images.jpg", write the actual name of the photo you are trying to upload. The photo should be in the same file where you've saved the .html file.

Comment: Despite the errors in the HTML, that code works fine when I test it. The problem is not exposed in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a code error on line 4 where head is closed. You missed the ">" sign.
Plus, the way you are tagging the image in html is incorrect. It should be the following:

```
<img src = "imagePath/ImageName.extention" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>GLOBAL WARMING</title>
</head
<body>
<img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

You can add image width & height as you like.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<img src="images.jpg"/>
```

Also make sure your path is correct.